# Maximal rank abelian subgroups of mapping class group

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, mapping-class-group

I'm currently getting involved with mapping class groups of surfaces ($MCG$). So for a genus g surface with b boundary components $S_{g,b}$ it is well-known that $MCG(S_{g,b})$ contains not only a lot of "weird" elements, but also is equipped with nice structures. By that I mean that $MCG(S_{g,b})$ contains a lot of abelian subgroups.

Finding some of these abelian subgroups is relatively simple, for example Dehn-Twists along non-intersecting curves generate abelian subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. But is there a way to find maximal rank abelian subgroups?

I know that there are bounds on the rank of abelian subgroups in $MCG(S_{g,b})$ by results of Atalan, but are there any statements on existence of a maximum rank abelian subgroup or how one would find them?

For example, it is also "well-known" that $MCG(S_{g,0})$ can be generated by 2g+1 Dehn-Twists, although in a non-abelian way. So what in that case, how would one find a maximum set of such Dehn-Twists such that their generated subgroup would be abelian? And in that case, is it really a maximum rank abelian subgroup of $MCG(S_{g,0})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of all maximal rank free abelian subgroups is well known as an application of Ivanov's subgroup theorem, and is described as follows.

First, cut $S_{g,0}$ along simple closed curves into pairs of pants, one-holed tori, four holed spheres, and annuli, such that each simple closed curve $\gamma$ in the collection bounds an annulus on one side of $\gamma$ and one of the other three types on the other side of $\gamma$. The number of non-pants components of this decomposition will be $3g-3$; list them as $C_1,...,C_{3g-3}$.

For each $i=1,...,3g-3$ define a homeomorphism $h_i$ which is the identity outside of $C_i$, and when restricted to $C_i$ is: a Dehn twist power if $C_i$ is an annulus; or a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism (up to isotopy) if $C_i$ is a one-holed torus or four holed sphere. The mapping classes of these homeomorphisms freely generate a maximal rank free abelian group, and all maximal rank free abelian groups arise in this manner.

A similar generalization holds for $S_{g,b}$.

Comment: By Ivanov's subgroup theorem, do you mean this metaconjecture stating, that every object associated to a surface $S$ has $MCG^{\pm}(S)$ as its automorphism group? I didn't find anything else relating to Ivanov subgroup theorem

Comment: Also, is it known how many distict subgroups there are? Maybe also up to conjugacy classes in $MCG(S_{g,b})$?

Comment: Ivanov's theorem refers to Theorem 3 in [these notes of my lecture back in 2007](https://www.math.utah.edu/~yael/MCG/MCG9.pdf), which don't have my name on them :-/

Comment: From the description given it's not hard to see that there are infinitely many free abelian subgroups, and infinitely many conjugacy classes. There's more to be said, but that's perhaps a topic for another question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the maximal rank is $3g-3+b$, see Theorem A in

*Birman, Joan S.; Lubotzky, Alex; McCarthy, John*, [**Abelian and solvable subgroups of the mapping class group**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-83-05046-9), Duke Math. J. 50, 1107-1120 (1983). [ZBL0551.57004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0551.57004).